# Preload google DFP iframes in case of infinite content

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-dfp

Is there way to preload google DFP iframes in case of infinite content?

I've followed example from page https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/4578089?hl=en

I wish not to see empty place and delay before ad loads.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the follow:

```
googletag.pubads().disableInitialLoad(); //preload the DFP iframes
googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs(true);
googletag.pubads().refresh([slot1]); //You need to refresh the slots to display
```

I hope this help.